# ESET Smart Security is showing updates to Windows 10 that are missing in Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, eset

I have installed a trial version of ESET Smart Security 9. It has a notification when there are new updates to Windows available. And currently it shows me 10 updates (interface is in Polish):

[image: ESET Updates window]

However, when I go to Windows Update (either by clicking "Run System Update" button or searching in start menu) there are no updates available:

[image: Windows Update]

In "Advance options" I have "Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows" checkbox checked.

Is this ESET's bug (but how does it know about these 10 updates?) or is Windows lying to me?

Comment: Manufacturer (Asus) doesn't provide drivers specifically for Windows 10 so I don't know where to download them from… Even for Windows 8 the latest is from 2013. A source where ESET gets them from would be helpful.

Comment: ESET support is saying that ESET Smart Security is showing also less critical updates (including optional). Is it possible to change the importance level in Windows Update setting to show also optional updates? I didn't find such an option…

Comment: Also using Windows Update API (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922132/use-c-sharp-to-interact-with-windows-update) I see these updates… All are marked as Recommended. How to install them via Windows Update interface?

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed is to go to Control Penel > Device Manager and expand each group of items, then rigtht click on each item shown and select Update Driver Software. This is better than using the manufacturer's websites as they very often don't have drivers listed for the latest Operating Systems. I checked ASUS website and there was nothing for Windows 10 x 64 Bit OS. However the method described above yeilded a range of new drivers dated 2015 & 2016. My own motherboard was purchased back in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (witam :)). Thanks to ESET I know that my drivers and some software installed in Win10 is not up-to-date. For hardware, there is a solution: manually find each hardware in device manager and update teh driver. You can also try to use alternative updaters like WSUS offline updater.

Comment: I finally used my own application to download and install updates that Windows is not showing. The code is based on this article: http://techforum4u.com/entry.php/11-Install-Windows-Update-Using-C